# Delay execution of IRP_MN_SET_POWER

Tags: windows, device-driver

I am developing a Windows device-driver and need to delay execution of a system shutdown for about 10 secs. I am using following code inside DispatchPower() function of my driver:

```
NTSTATUS DispatchPower(
  __in  struct _DEVICE_OBJECT *DeviceObject,
  __in  struct _IRP *Irp
)
{

    switch(stack->MinorFunction)
    {
        case IRP_MN_SET_POWER:            
            delay_time.QuadPart = WDF_REL_TIMEOUT_IN_SEC(10);
            KeDelayExecutionThread(KernelMode, FALSE, &delay_time);
    }

}
```

But it seems KeDelayExecutionThread() returns immediately without waiting? Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not certain, but here are some advices:

1. Check the return value of `KeDelayExecutionThread`. According to the docs it *seems* that this function may return preliminary with either `STATUS_ALERTED` or `STATUS_USER_APC`. Well, since you're performing a non-alertable state this should not happen, but OTOH I don't quite understand what is the difference between `STATUS_ALERTED` and `STATUS_USER_APC`. Besides from this it may return you an error status, which may be informative.
2. According to the docs you must run at IRQL <= `APC_LEVEL`. You should check your actual IRQL (`KeGetCurrentIrql`).
3. Anyway, IMHO it's a pretty weird design to block a thread in the kernel-mode. Usually this hangs the whole system. If you want to delay the IRP processing you'd better return `STATUS_PENDING` in the dispatch routine, and then, via timer DPC complete this IRP.

If you're not familiar with this read the MSDN about the following: `KeInitializeDpc`, `KeInitializeTimer`, `KeSetTimer`.

Comment: STATUS_ALERTED means that someone alerted your thread with the undocumented ZwAlertThread API. STATUS_USER_APC means an APC was queued to the thread, such as with the Win32 API QueueUserApc.

Comment: Didn't know about `ZwAlertThread` (sounds like an ugly hack). I think that `STATUS_USER_APC` is returned **after** the scheduled APC has been executed. At least this is so in the alertable user-mode wait

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer was a good one, blocking in a power thread like this is discouraged (even in the docs). Why do you need a 10 second delay in the first place?

-scott